# PHP Session var through AJAX problem

Tags: php, ajax

is it possible to define a PHP Session var through AJAX? I'm doing it in the background of a script and it seems to be kind of random.

Comment: is the ajax call going to a PHP page on the same server?  you should be able to access the session var in the other php page you are calling.

or are you asking if you can pass the value in an ajax call - that should also be doable, depending on how you are formatting your ajax request.

Comment: Yes it's on the same server. When the user clicks on an item it registers its ID in a session var through AJAX, so that when he clicks on a button it goes to another AJAX PHP page (in the background) that uses the same session var to do an SQL request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most definitely.  As long as the AJAX endpoint is on the same server as the rest of your site, this will definitely work.

Remember, AJAX is HTTP messaging just like any other normal web page request.  This means any registered cookies for the domain will be sent with those AJAX requests, which means the session can be used.